# What setting do I need to tweak in Visual Studio 2012 to edit markup inline, and see changes upon refreshing the browser while debugging?

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2012

I just migrated to Visual Studio 2012, and am working on some CSS changes for a web application.  In Visual Studio 2010, I used to be able to launch the web application in debugger, edit the markup inline for partial views, refresh the browser, and see those changes immediately reflected in the browser.

Now when I do the same thing in Visual Studio 2012, I don't see the changes at all. Doing a hard refresh in the browser, and even dumping cache doesn't do it.  I can edit the CSS file, and those changes will appear upon refreshing the browser.

But when I edit the markup side of the partial view, that change doesn't show up unless I stop debugging, close the browser, and start the debugger again.  This is very tedious, and I have a lot of CSS changes to make in a short period of time.

Thanks for your help.